# Drupal 7 - relative menu with childrens or parents

Tags: php, drupal, menu, drupal-7

I'm working on site using Drupal 7 and there is panel which prints relative menu of current page. For example my menu looks like this:

```
MENU PRIMARY
-SUBMENU
--LINK 1
--LINK 2
---sublink 1
---sublink 2
--LINK 3
```

When I'm on node `sublink 1` menu shows:

```
LINK 2
--sublink 1 (active)
--sublink 2
```

Problem is when I enter for example `LINK 3` which doesn't have childs and menu shows only title of current node

```
LINK 3
```

In this case I would like to show all releative links to this  current page so it should look like this:

```
LINK 1
LINK 2
LINK 3 (active)
```

I have no idea how to check this and print correct menu. 
Here is my function which handle this:

```
function mysite_relative_main_menu() {
  $menu_name = variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu');

  $parents = menu_get_active_trail();
  array_shift($parents);
  $expanded_parents = array_filter($parents, function($item){
    return !@$item["expanded"];
  });
  if (count($expanded_parents) > 1) {
    array_shift($expanded_parents);
  }
  $parent = current($expanded_parents);
  if (!$parent) {
    return NULL;
  }

  $main_tree = menu_tree_all_data($menu_name, NULL, NULL);
  $flat_tree = $main_tree;
  $walk_over_trees = function($tree) use(&$flat_tree, &$walk_over_trees) {
    foreach ($tree as $data) {
      foreach ($data["below"] as $tree) {
        $flat_tree[] = $tree;

        if ($tree["below"]) {
          call_user_func_array($walk_over_trees, [[$tree]]);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  call_user_func_array($walk_over_trees, [$main_tree]);

  $subtree = [current(array_filter($flat_tree, function($data) use($parent) {
    return $data["link"]["link_path"] == $parent["link_path"];
  }))];

  $tree_output_prepare = menu_tree_output($subtree);

  $list = drupal_render($tree_output_prepare);
  $list = substr_replace($list, "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\"", strpos($list, "<ul "), 3);

  return $list;
}
```

I would be grateful for any advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you take a look at menu block?
https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block
It's a module that let you be really flexible on deeper levels of the menu

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks interesting. I will give it a try ;) Anyway, for future, if somebody knows programmatically solution I would be glad to hear it ;)